# How can I compute the derivative of delta function using its Fourier definition?

Tags: fourier-transform, differentiation, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

I am wondering if it's possible to compute the derivative of the Dirac Delta function using the definition obtained from Fourier transformation: $$\delta(x-x')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{-ik(x-x')}dk.$$
What I have attempted is the following (all the integrals are from -infinity to +infinity):
$$\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-x') = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int \frac{d}{dx}e^{-ik(x-x')}dk=\frac{-1}{2\pi} \int e^{-ik(x-x')} \cdot ik dk$$
$$=\frac{-1}{2\pi} \left\{\frac{-ke^{-ik(x-x')}}{x-x'}\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ik(x-x')}}{x-x'}dk\right\}$$
If the first term would to be zero, then the second term would become $\frac{-\delta(x-x')}{x-x'}$. Intuitively, this should be the derivative of the Delta function: when $x'$ is approached from the left, its derivative goes from 0 to infinity; from the right, the derivative goes from 0 to negative infinity. However, I have not been able to show that the first term is indeed zero. Can you prove/disprove this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first term is *not* zero in any direct sense, in fact the expression clearly diverges. The reason that in physics you can get away with *pretending* it is zero is that $\delta$ and its derivative $\delta'$ aren't actually functions with a converging Fourier expansion in the first place, but, as they are often called, *distributions*.

In my opinion the easiest way to understand it is that they're *dual vectors* of a function space. Specifically, $\delta$ is in the dual of the space $(\mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{R}))^\ast$ of the space of continuous functions, and $\delta'$ is in $(\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}))^\ast$ i.e. continuously differentiable functions. An easy and rigorous way to define them is
$$\begin{align}
  \delta_{x_0} \: f :=& f(x_0) \\
  \delta'_{x_0} \: f :=& -f'(x_0)
\end{align}$$
i.e. the argument of $\delta$ is actually a *function*, not a real number. Anything written in the $\delta(x-x')$ style is in fact just pseudo-notation, that only becomes well-defined when it appears in an integral:
$$\begin{align}
  \int_\Omega\!\!\mathrm{d}x\ \delta(x-x_0) \cdot f(x) := \delta_{x_0}\:f =& f(x_0) & \text{if $x_0\in\Omega$}
\end{align}$$
Equivalently, you can do all of this in Fourier space. The expansion $\delta(x) \propto \int\mathrm{d}k\ e^{-ikx}$ doesn't actually converge by itself, however it does converge when frequency-wise multiplied with the Fourier transform of a continuous function, because such an expansion has coeffients decaying with at least $O(k^{-1})$, so
$$
  \|e^{-ikx} \cdot\operatorname{FT}(f)(k)\| \leq O(k^{-1})
$$
and an oscillating function that decays in that way *can* be integrated.

Likewise, the Fourier expansion you derived for $\delta'$ does make sense after you multiply it frequency-wise with the expansion of a continuously differentiable function, because that decays in $O(k^{-2})$ and therefore
$$
  \bigl(\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\:\delta(x-x')\bigr)\:f(x)
   \propto \left.\left[\frac{-k\cdot e^{-ik(x-x')}}{x-x'}\cdot O(k^{-2})\right]\right|_{-\infty}^\infty + \ldots
$$
and here $k\cdot O(k^{-2})$ gives something in $O(k^{-1})$, which therefore does vanish at infinity meaning your derivation is correct.

Comment: Every question on MSE involving delta functions should probably get routed to this answer first. :)